# Python library is not requesting access token

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to get the access token using the library rauth,and urllib and JSON. So I'm trying to produce a access token with the token type of bearer. So I'm able to produce the token via Postman without any problems and trying to replicate it in python.

So in the header of postman I have key:authorization and value of Basic and some key. My body in postman has grant_type,username,password and it's a JSON type. The result is a access_token,token_type of bearer,refreshtoken,expires in and scope.

```
import urllib
from rauth import OAuth2Service
import json


grant_type = "password"
username = "***"
password="***"

payload = {
    'grant_type': grant_type,
    'username': username,
    'password':password
}

url = "***";

r = requests.post(url,
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},
    data=payload)

body = json.loads(r.content)
token = body["accessToken"]
expiresIn = body[10799]
print (token)
```

Comment: What is `url` equal to?

Comment: I can't share url because is connecting to a private server. I'm trying to find a bearer token using this data.

Comment: Have you tried using a session and doing GET to load up cookies into the session before the POST?

Comment: Also what error are you getting from your attempted login?